# Why does Bazel http_archive rule not download archive?

Tags: c++, bazel, googletest

I'm a Bazel newbie and am working through the C++ guide here, trying to include an external testing library (gtest): https://bazel.build/tutorials/cpp-use-cases#include-external-libraries

This is my file structure and WORKSPACE and BUILD file contents:

```
$ tree
.
├── gtest.BUILD
├── lib
│   ├── BUILD
│   ├── hello-time.cc
│   └── hello-time.h
├── main
│   ├── BUILD
│   ├── hello-greet.cc
│   ├── hello-greet.h
│   └── hello-world.cc
├── README.md
├── test
│   ├── BUILD
│   └── hello-test.cc
└── WORKSPACE
```

Contents of WORKSPACE:

```
$ cat WORKSPACE 
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(
    name = "gtest",
    build_file = "@//:gtest.BUILD",
    url = "https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/release-1.10.0.zip",
    sha256 = "94c634d499558a76fa649edb13721dce6e98fb1e7018dfaeba3cd7a083945e91",
)
```

Contents of gtest.BUILD:

```
$ cat gtest.BUILD 
cc_library(
    name = "main",
    srcs = glob(
        ["src/*.cc"],
        exclude = ["src/gtest-all.cc"]
    ),
    hdrs = glob([
        "include/**/*.h",
        "src/*.h"
    ]),
    copts = ["-Iexternal/gtest/include"],
    linkopts = ["-pthread"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

Contents of test/BUILD:

```
$ cat test/BUILD 
cc_test(
    name = "hello-test",
    srcs = ["hello-test.cc"],
    copts = ["-Iexternal/gtest/include"],
    deps = [
        "@gtest//:main",
        "//main:hello-greet",
    ],
)
```

I then try to run "bazel test test:hello-test" but it throws an issue complaining about a missing "BUILD" file:

```
ERROR: An error occurred during the fetch of repository 'gtest':
   Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
Error in read: Unable to load package for //:gtest.BUILD: BUILD file not found in any of the following directories. Add a BUILD file to a directory to mark it as a package.
 - /home/user/code/bazelbuild_examples/cpp-tutorial/stage4
```

I then ran "touch BUILD" in the top level directory, after finding a GitHub issue with a similar error message, which got rid of that error.

Bazel is now downloading gtest library (can see it under "bazel-stage4/external/gtest") but it doesn't seem to be making it available to the test target:

```
ERROR: /home/user/code/bazelbuild_examples/cpp-tutorial/stage4/test/BUILD:1:8: Compiling test/hello-test.cc failed: (Exit 1): gcc failed: error executing command /usr/bin/gcc -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-pointer '-std=c++0x' -MD -MF ... (remaining 25 arguments skipped)

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox
test/hello-test.cc:1:10: fatal error: gtest/gtest.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include "gtest/gtest.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Why is it unable to find the gtest headers/library? How does the directory layout work when you're running "bazel test"? (i.e. where is the test code directory relative to the 3rd party library directory?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem has to do with your gtest build file.  First, *google test* comes with a supported Bazel BUILD file already, so why write your own instead of using theirs?

Second:

```
cc_library(
    name = "main",
    srcs = glob(
        ["src/*.cc"],
        exclude = ["src/gtest-all.cc"]
    ),
    hdrs = glob([
        "include/**/*.h",
        "src/*.h"
    ]),
    copts = ["-Iexternal/gtest/include"],
    linkopts = ["-pthread"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

The path that c++ source code would have to #include for headers in this rule is "include/.../*.h".  That's not proper.  For one, `copts` affects **this** rule, but not other targets that depend on it.  In general, compiler options should be part of the toolchain, not the rule like this.  Second, *cc_library* rules have an `includes = []` argument specifically for fixing include paths to strip leading prefixes.  Instead of `copts` you should use `includes` to fix the path-------BUT you should use the official google test BUILD file instead of writing your own and not have to deal with problems like this.

Comment: Thank you for that! I wasn't particularly concerned about using my own BUILD file, just wanted to know how referencing third party packages works. Trying to use the provided BUILD file (BUILD.bazel) I am having trouble referencing it though. It is not automatically picked up and using 'build_file = "@//gtest:BUILD.bazel",'  in the WORKSPACE file, it complains about it not being marked as a package? Solution is to put an empty build file in the extracted directory apparently, so that it's marked as a "package". Looking at how to do this, do people use genrules or macros for this?

Comment: In the end I switched to using the git_repository rule instead: "git_repository(
  name = "gtest2",
  remote = "https://github.com/google/googletest.git",
  branch = "main",
)"
which managed to find/load the BUILD file fine.

Comment: http_archive is better than git_repository because it can deal with local caches without having to hit the remote server, based on the SHA256